# Symfony Form DateTimeType: I can't map violations on subform date and time separately

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form that looks like that :

```
$builder->add('start', DateTimeType::class, [
    'label'       => false,
    'widget'      => null,
    'date_label'  => 'test1',
    'date_widget' => 'single_text',
    'time_label'  => 'test2',
    'time_widget' => 'single_text',
]);
```

Then I have a specific process that makes me manually add violation to my form like that :

```
[...]

// use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ViolationMapper\ViolationMapper;
$violationMapper = new ViolationMapper();

/** @var array<int, string> $globalErrors */
$globalErrors = $extendedMessage['global_errors'];
foreach ($globalErrors as $error) {
    $constraint = new ConstraintViolation($error, $error, [], '', null, null);
    $violationMapper->mapViolation($constraint, $form);
}

/** @var array<string, array<int, string>> $propertyErrors */
$propertyErrors = $extendedMessage['property_errors'];
foreach ($propertyErrors as $property => $errors) {
        // at the first occurrence $property looks like that : 'children[start].children[date]'
        // at the second occurrence $property looks like that : 'children[start].children[time]'
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        // use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation;
        $constraint = new ConstraintViolation($error, $error, [], '', $property, null);
        $violationMapper->mapViolation($constraint, $form); // <<< RIGHT HERE is where it breaks or dont behave like I expect it to...
    }
}
```

The errors just get mapped on `start` instead of `start.date` or `start.time`... any idea how to proceed so that errors goes on the right subfield ?

I have tried multiple propertyPath formats but did not found solution yet, i tried

- children[start].children[date]
- children[start][date]
- children[start].date
- children[start[date]] (this one causes exception)
- children[start.date]